# How many ordered pairs (A,B) , where A , B are subsets of {1,2,3,4,5} have: |A∩B|=1

Tags: combinatorics

if A ,  B  are subsets of  {1,2,3,4,5}  How many ordered pairs  (A,B)  have:
|A∩B|=1

Comment: some give me hint to solve this question

Comment: If you find this difficult try answering the same question first for a simpler set, say $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Look at my answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315873/how-many-ordered-pairs-a-b-where-a-b-are-subsets-of-1-2-3-4-5-have   There we had $1$ as a common element, in your question you can have **any one** of the $1,2,3,4,5$ as a common element, so.....

Answer (score 0):

[image] Hint :- consider the element $ 5 $ is the only common element then from the figure the choices for $ A $ and $ B $ can be the last three displayed options only ( think why ? )

Comment: First, 1 is in both A and B. Then, 2,3,4,5 has 3 choices, in A, in B or neither. So there are $3^4$=81 combinations.

Comment: but 81 is wrong for this

Comment: @raj No it isn't...

Comment: If you have the answer then please update it in the post and what you did too ! Don't just post questions